# Configure Roslyn analyser in Azure Devops Yaml

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, yaml, roslyn

I need help. I am trying to configure roslyn code analyser in azure devops. I need the MsCommandLine to add this roslyn analyser.
[image]

and the build task generated is

```
- task: RoslynAnalyzers@3   inputs:
    userProvideBuildInfo: 'msBuildInfo'
    msBuildVersion: '16.0'
    msBuildArchitecture: 'amd64'
    msBuildCommandline: '$(Parameters.solution)'
```

But i am getting error

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The
>   current working directory does not   contain a project or solution
>   file.

What should be added in MSBuildCommandLine to specify source directory of the project? 
I have referred to https://secdevtools.azurewebsites.net/helpRoslynAnalyzers.html
and https://www.1eswiki.com/wiki/Secure_Development_Tools_Extension_For_Azure_DevOps . 
I am not getting any clue about this MSCommandLine. How to specify it?

Comment: I think you got the wrong stackoverflow

Comment: @sam did u find the solution to ur problem. I have same issue to be resolved...?

Answer (score 0):

The commandline should begin with a full path to `MSBuild.exe`.
The command will run with $(Build.SourcesDirectory) as the working directory. You may specify the full path to `MSBuild.exe`, and try again.

Comment: I know this was in hint. It doesnt work or may be I am not doing it correctly. Can you give an example how the commandline should look like?

Comment: How do you specify the solution file? Is this extension not public?

Answer (score 0):

The commandline should begin with a full path to MSBuild.exe or dotnet.exe. So your msBuildCommandline statement should look like below

msBuildCommandline: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build '$(Parameters.solution)' ...

Comment: MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
    Switch: '**/*.sln
    Failed to run the command: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build '**/*.sln 
    /p:PreferredToolArchitecture=amd64 /p:Features="IOperation,flow-analysis" 
    /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=false /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false
    Roslyn analysis failed.
    Start copying Roslyn analysis results ...

Comment: It is failing..I am not sure which project file doesnt exist... Why is this failing?

Comment: Try with giving absolute path for sln file. Example:  task: ms-codeanalysis.vss-microsoft-security-code-analysis-devops.build-task-roslynanalyzers.RoslynAnalyzers@2
  displayName: 'Run Roslyn Analyzers'
  inputs:
    userProvideBuildInfo: msBuildInfo
    msBuildArchitecture: DotNetCore
    msBuildCommandline: '"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\YourSolName.sln'